# Does a Promotion Series have time constraints?

Tags: league-of-legends

In other words, how long can you be inactive in ranked before you're kicked out of a promotion series?

Comment: Dodging a match, however, will end the series. Just something to keep in mind :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of June 2013, promotion series now have time constraints. The series ends after 28 days of inactivity.

[Source](http://forums.euw.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1322847)

Answer (score 3):

No, the series only ends once you have played those 3 games. They can be be played over any length of time.

[Source](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?p=34239988#34239988)

Comment: What if you stop playing for 28 days and rating decay takes place? Would that kick you out of a promotion series?

Comment: [This](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?p=34311835) is the best I could find to help, but it doesn't mention any about it affecting your series. Once you qualify for it though, I'm assuming it wouldn't kick you out.

Comment: @SadlyNot You've got it backwards; in S3, rating decay will apply only to your progression (LP), not to your elo (MMR).

Comment: @Yves My bad :)

Comment: I'm going to have to say this answer is incorrect from personal experience. I hit my promotion series, won my first game and have not played a ranked game since that time. I am now back at 100 LP with no wins towards a promotion series. I don't know what caused this, and I'm fairly certain it hasn't been over a month since that last ranked match.

Comment: Found out my previous comment wasn't correct, just played my first ranked game since it happened. I still had the 100 LP, but after winning the match I was advanced into Silver I as the win counted as my second win for the promotion series, so this answer is in fact still correct.

Comment: Incorrect, it can be played anytime *within 28 days*. Also say you play at day 20, the countdown gets a reset so you can have another 28 days.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. I don't know why the top answer says you cannot be kicked out because that is false information. Decay is a thing in league of legends which causes you to lose lp over not being active for a period of time. If you do not play for 28 days from getting into your series, you will be kicked out of it.
http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=3742674